# Commands not executing after a statements

Tags: vb.net

I have some code in Form Load event.  It is doing fine.  But when it reaches to pick data from database, no commands are executing after that.  There is no error at all but it just goes silent.

I tested it as follows:

```
MsgBox("1")
vrStudentName = DsGetPprStatusfromEnrSummary.tblPaperEnrSummary.Rows(0).Item("StudentName")
MsgBox("2")
```

Please advise.
Thanks
Furqan

Message Box one is showing data but not the message box two.  In fact, the second message box statement is not showing any response at all.

Comment: Are you getting an exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a nasty problem on 64-bit operating systems.  Any exception raised in code that's run from a form's Load event is swallowed without a diagnostic.  This is an old problem that is not getting solved because the DevDiv and the Windows groups at Microsoft are pointing fingers at each other.  My finger is pointing at the Windows group but that doesn't help either.

Two basic ways to solve this problem:

- Project + Properties, Compile tab, scroll down, Advanced Compile Options, change the Target CPU option from x86 to AnyCPU.  This disables the Wow64 emulation layer that swallows the exception.
- Debug + Exceptions, tick the Thrown box for "Common Language Runtime Exceptions".  The debugger stops as soon as the exception is thrown.

Also keep in mind that it is very rarely necessary to use the OnLoad method or Load event.  Only code that requires the Size or Location or Handle of the form to be accurate needs it.  Anything else belongs in the constructor of the form.  That Load is used so often is a VB6 anachronism, carried over in the designer design which made the Load event the default event for a Form.  Add a constructor by typing "Sub New".

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems pretty obvious that the call to `DsGetPprStatusfromEnrSummary.tblPaperEnrSummary` is never returning; which means the problem is IN THERE somewhere.

So what on eath is it? I'm guessing it's a DataSet, yes?

But you've referenced it staticly, which is YuckyPooPoo(TM) IMHO, because it's a complex artifact, and you've rendered EVERYTHING which references it unisolatable, and therefore fundamentally untestable!

Answer (score 0):

Received answer on Codeproject

In the dialog that comes up, put a tick in every checkbox under both "Thrown" and "Unhandled". Press OK.
Now, when you run your app though the debugger, it will break for any exception, even if you have an active handler. This should help you track down the problem.

Issue RESOLVED

Comment: It is not an answer, just a workaround.  It will byte you again.